# solidity interface - Contracts calling unimplemented functions

Tags: solidity, chainlink, interfaces, solidity-0.6.x

I'm new to solidity and OOP. I'm trying to understand the code in this simple lottery game example:

https://github.com/alphachainio/chainlink-lottery/blob/master/ethereum/contracts/

I am confused when they call `governance.randomness()` in line 57 in Lottery.sol. but I don't see the `randomness()` function  implemented any where in any of the contract files.

The answer below explains that the unimplemented function will be implemented in the contract provided in `CEth cToken = CEth(_cEtherContract);`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64734548/4488843

But in the GitHub lottery example, I see the function is no where declared in any of the contracts (lottery.sol, randomness.sol and governance.sol).

is the function initiated when governance contract's `init()` function is called and it sets the `randomness` state variable? or is there something I'm missing in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `randomness` example it is important to know that Solidity generates getters for all public variables. In the `governance` contract there is a public variable `randomness` which generates the mentioned function as a getter: https://github.com/alphachainio/chainlink-lottery/blob/master/ethereum/contracts/Governance.sol#L6.

In general Solidity does not perform any check if a contract implements a specific interface when casting it to that interface. More info on this can be found here: [How is an interface initialised?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118208/how-is-an-interface-initialised/118212) (there are quite some other questions also explaining this ;) )

Comment: I understand it creates a getter function for public variables. But Where is the init function from governance.sol called? I think this sets the randomness and lottery state variables?

Comment: It is just a getter, so until `init` is called the `randomness()` function will return the 0-Address, as this is the default value for uninitialized addresses.